# Add reference to .dll asp.net

Tags: asp.net, reference, recaptcha

I have a simple question about adding references to a .NET project. I'm adding reCAPTCHA to a website and i have downloaded the dll.

After setting the reference to the dll i build and run the project and gets this error:

```
[ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.]
   System.Reflection.Module._GetTypesInternal(StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +0
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() +96
   StarSuite.Core.Settings.GetSingletonInstancesOfBaseType(Type baseType, String staticMethodName, Type returnType) +149

[ApplicationException: Unable to load types from 'Recaptcha, Version=1.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9afc4d65b28c38c2'. LoaderExceptions: [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
]
```

What am i missing, why do i get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if the question is silly...Is it your web project MVC? It seems that If you're using web form based project you shouldn't use that component since it relies on mvc assemblies (maybe there is a web form version?).

Comment: I haven't used that component, but I'd say you should check this  project on google code http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/aspnet.html

Comment: I tryed an older version of the component and i seams to work! Thank you all very much for your help and time!!!

Answer (score 1):

**File Not Found**:

This is you reason - its in the output:

```
FileNotFoundException
```

Double check where your reference is pointing to

Comment: But i clearly have the file and browse to it when i add the reference?

Comment: Can you take a look at the reference properties and post both what its path is and what explorer says it path is?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the DLL under references in your project so it will be included in the build?

Comment: I don't have a references folder in the project?

Comment: I'm talking about the References Folder in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

For people finding this whilst searching for a fix for Umbraco, the fix can be found here:

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/xslt/19383-referencing-catcha-dll-breaks-xslt

The same fix can be applied to websites that are not running Umbraco.

Summary to save you having to read the whole forum post, add this to your web config:

```
<runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0"
          newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
```